# How to dynamic calculate value using formulas in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, calculation, auto

I'm in new this field. How do I manage the dynamic calculation with formulas and what steps to achieve the below output?.

I have tables.

Table 1 - **Info_question** table is for details about questions name and id.

| q_id | questions_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

Table 2 - **data_question** is for data values.

| id | q_id | period | data_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021 | 2000 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022 | 3000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022 | 4000 |
| 5 | 4 | 2022 | 5000 |

I need to calculate **A+B+C** and that output will insert into **data_question** table and new question will create in the **info_question** table.(formulas will change for new question like A/B*100 or A+C and question id will be new generate)

**For (A+B+C) Output should be shows like below tables.**

**data_question** table

| id | q_id | period | data_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021 | 2000 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022 | 3000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022 | 4000 |
| 5 | 4 | 2022 | 5000 |
| 6 | 5 | 2022 | **8000** |
| 7 | 5 | 2021 | **2000** |

and **info_question**

| q_id | questions_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| **5** | **E** |